# Building an MSSQL database with ColdFusion or Java from an ".sql" file?

Tags: java, ant, coldfusion, database-schema, sqljdbc

I have a .sql file that was created using the MS SQL Management Studio Script Wizard. It contains the entire database schema including **views**, **stored procedures**, tables, indexes, etc.

**I’m looking for a way to automate the process of creating the database with ColdFusion or Java or even .NET.**

I’ve tried using CFQUERY but it throws all kinds of errors with the .sql file.

I’ve tried using ANT with sqljdbc4.jar but it also fails on the first line with a “[sql] Failed to execute:  BEGIN TRAN” com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near ''.

Comment: Post some of your Java setup so we can help you more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly doubt you can use the scripts generated by the wizard outside of an MS tool. The wizard makes copious use of `GO` [which is not standard T-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx). Also, commands like `CREATE PROCEDURE` need to be the first statement within the batch. To run the wizard scripts, you need to use an MS tool like [sqlcmd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx). With the correct permissions, you should be able to run `sqlcmd.exe` from `<cfexecute>`.

Comment: Thanks Leigh. I discovered sqlcmd.exe shortly after posting the question. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to execute all the SQL within a <cfquery assuming you have the appropriate permissions.

We generate all our databases like this with CREATES etc in a ColdFusion <cfquery

Do you have the appropriate permissions, what errors are you getting.

Comment: The wizards usually add client `GO` commands, which do not work within a cfquery.

Comment: Aside from removing non-standard T-SQL ("GO" statements are pretty rampant), also check that the DSN settings allow for multiple statements to be run. I haven't setup an MSSQL DSN in a while, but this is how you do it for MySQL: https://img.skitch.com/20111021-d9m2f62wg6983wc5myt7qhnqji.png

Comment: FYI: Unlike mySQL, multiple statements work out right of the box for MS SQL DSN's.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ORM, you may set `this.ormsettings.sqlscript` to point to your .sql file in `Application.cfc` and it'll be run on `ORMReload()` when `this.ormsettings.dbcreate` is set to `dropcreate`.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSED380324-6CBE-47cb-9E5E-26B66ACA9E81.html

Good luck